# digital clock in android

Tags: android

friends.
I want to put my personal drawable fonts in digital clock for showing time. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Add fonts to your asset folder and then use them in your project.

[Example is here](http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/05/android-development-using-custom-fonts/).

Comment: ** but its not a fonts its a drawable images .suppose the time is 1.12 at that i want ti not defaulkt one my own drawable images and like that seperate images from 0-9 ,so please suggest me anything .

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement a BitMap font. Here is a nice tutorial:

http://obviam.net/index.php/using-bitmap-fonts-in-android/